# Jquery html css

Tags: jquery

Hi I am facing a jquery runtime error.

**Error**

> Unable to get property 'initialize' of undefined or null reference

Below is the snippet of my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
  window.onload = function () {
    var test = $('#perfect-scrollbar');
    var Ps;
    Ps.initialize(test);
    [].forEach.call(test.querySelectorAll('.element'), function (el) {
      el.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function () {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        Ps.update(perfect-scrollbar);
      });
    });
  };

});
```

Comment: @Akshay not null, but undefined

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need the line

```
var Ps;
```

as that should come from the perfect scrollbar object instead.

Also, looking at https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/ it would appear your update line should be

```
Ps.update(test);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but now i'm facing another error "Unable to get property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined or null reference"